# Score is being over written cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

The high score isn't staying on screen at all so the big problem is what do I do so the score will stay on screen until it is surpassed and will update score like a high score.

I have taken advice from another user couple days ago  that made it seem simple ,but when I tried to do it didn't work out. I tried pretty much all the different types of combinations and no beans. So looks like I need someones help pointing out the error.

init

```
 _oldScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"]; 
 CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
    _scoreLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width - _scoreLabel.contentSize.width, _scoreLabel.contentSize.height);
    _scoreLabel.color = ccc3(255,0,0);
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel z:1];
```

implementation

```
 if (_score > _oldScore) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_score forKey:@"score"];          
       [_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score%d", _score]];
```

So far it works great, and everything but the  oldscore won't stay on the screen. I want the player to know what the high score is.
The user said make a new nsuserdefaults with a different  key to store old score. So that way old score with the highest score will stay on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// To save score in preference

```
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"score"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

// To get saved value from  preference

```
highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue ];
```

//To set score value to ur cocos2d label

```
[_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _oldScore]];
```